# Getting magic function to work in PHP Soap Client

Tags: php, soap, client, soap-client

I'm using the PHP Soap Client with a WSDL document.The client is created like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://eklima.met.no/metdata/MetDataService?WSDL');
```

Now I want to call the function 'getCountyTypes' which takes to parameters 'language' and 'countiesId'.

```
$args = array(
    'language'=>'no', 
    'countiesId'=>'2'
);
```

Directly using the function __soapCall works as expected:

```
$res = $client->__soapCall('getCountyTypes', $args);
```

Trying to use magic functions does not work:

```
$res = $client->getCountyTypes($args);
```

I get the following error:

```
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /Users/jorgen/soaptest.php on line 60
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] No mapping found for ':countiesId' using encoding style 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'. [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] in /Users/jorgen/soaptest.php:60
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/jorgen/soaptest.php(60): SoapClient->__call('getCountyTypes', Array)
#1 /Users/jorgen/soaptest.php(60): MySoapClient->getCountyTypes(Array)
#2 {main}
  thrown in /Users/jorgen/soaptest.php on line 60
```

I need some directions on how to use the soap client with magic functions.

**Edit:** Added output from var_dump($client->__getFunctions());

```
array(14) {
  [0]=>
  string(185) "no_met_metdata_Metdata getMetData(string $timeserietypeID, string $format, string $from, string $to, string $stations, string $elements, string $hours, string $months, string $username)"
  [1]=>
  string(106) "ArrayOfno_met_metdata_TimeSerieTypes getTimeserieTypesProperties(string $language, string $timeserieTypes)"
  [2]=>
  string(99) "ArrayOfno_met_metdata_ElementProperties getElementsProperties(string $language, string $elem_codes)"
  [3]=>
  string(93) "ArrayOfno_met_metdata_ElementProperties getElementsFromTimeserieType(string $timeserietypeID)"
  [4]=>
  string(111) "ArrayOfno_met_metdata_ElementProperties getElementsFromTimeserieTypeStation(string $timeserietypeID, int $stnr)"
  [5]=>
  string(97) "ArrayOfno_met_metdata_StationProperties getStationsProperties(string $stations, string $username)"
  [6]=>
  string(111) "ArrayOfno_met_metdata_StationProperties getStationsFromTimeserieType(string $timeserietypeID, string $username)"
  [7]=>
  string(140) "ArrayOfno_met_metdata_StationProperties getStationsFromTimeserieTypeElemCodes(string $timeserietypeID, string $elem_codes, string $username)"
  [8]=>
  string(162) "ArrayOfno_met_metdata_StationProperties getStationsFromTimeserieTypeStationsElemCode(string $timeserietype, string $stations, string $elem_code, string $username)"
  [9]=>
  string(22) "string getDateFormat()"
  [10]=>
  string(89) "ArrayOfno_met_metdata_FlagProperties getFlagProperties(string $language, string $flagsId)"
  [11]=>
  string(110) "ArrayOfno_met_metdata_PrecipitationTypes getPrecipitationTypes(string $language, string $precipitationTypesId)"
  [12]=>
  string(33) "ArrayOfString getValidLanguages()"
  [13]=>
  string(86) "ArrayOfno_met_metdata_CountyTypes getCountyTypes(string $language, string $countiesId)"
}
```

Comment: can you do $client = new SoapClient($wsdl_url);
var_dump($client->__getFunctions()); and paste the Vardumped data here so that we can see what actually is the problem

Comment: I added the output to the question. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: What actually you are expecting do you want to use magic method __call to execute this because this  $res = $client->getCountyTypes($args); does not work at any time because the right way of doing is different

Comment: What is the correct way of doing this? How can I call the function directly on the client object? It seems possible according to various examples I have found.

Comment: $res = $client->__soapCall('getCountyTypes', $args); itself is a correct way of doing __call function is deprecated now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [aravind.udayashankara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1067466/aravind-udayashankara) the correct solution is to use

```
$res = $client->__soapCall('getCountyTypes', $args);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I thought I had to do something like the following:

```
$args = array(
    'language'=>'no', 
    'countiesId'=>'2' );

$res = $client->getCountyTypes($args);
```

But actually I had to do:

```
$res = $client->getCountyTypes("no","2");
```